# Could the table type argument input of store procedure table be optional

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I give a table type variable input in the store procedure definition, when user uses this store procedure, the table input is must needed?

I find I can not assign a default null to the table input...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parameter value not provided, defaults to empty table.

Check this:

```
CREATE TYPE tblType AS TABLE
(
id INT, name VARCHAR(30)
);

alter proc testTabl(
 @t tblType  READONLY 
 ) 
As
select * from @t

exec testTabl
```

So here if you dnt provide table valued parameter bydefault it will be set to empty table.